# Create JSON object with arrays using PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I create following type JSON object using PHP? I want this JSON for my Android app.

```
    {
  "grade 3": [
    {
      "section": "A",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
    },
    {
      "section": "B",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Penguins.jpg"
    },
    {
      "section": "C",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Penguins.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "grade 2": [
    {
      "section": "A",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
    },
    {
      "section": "B",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Penguins.jpg"
    },
    {
      "section": "C",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Penguins.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "grade 1": [
    {
      "section": "CD 1",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
    },
    {
      "section": "CD 2",
      "img_url": "http://lyceumssports.com/Penguins.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I want JSON object having arrays with keys an that array also has JSON Objects.

Comment: json_encode is your friend

Comment: Did you checked the json_decode and json_encode functions?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use a php function called `json_encode($array)`. Pass the array into the function and it will give you the json object. 
If you want to print JSON object beautifully then add an extra argument `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, like `json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`. Store this object into a variable and use that variable. On the other side you need to decode the JSON object, like in php,

```
$json_object=json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$json_decode=json_decode($json_object);
```

For more details see this link, [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).